# Google App Engine ( GAE ) and static files best practices

Tags: python, google-app-engine, optimization, static

I'm trying to create kind of instagram application, and I'm learning GAE so I would like to create the whole application with it.

The problem I see is that serving images to the client will consume a lot of traffic and I don't want that since Google bills you for that.

My question is: which are the best practices working with images in GAE?

My first idea is to have another server for everything static: CSS, PNGs, JPGs, etc... in another server, and just do the logic on GAE.

This way If someday I need it I can migrate to Amazon or whatever, since the logic shouls scale perfectly with GAE ( if is well programmed :) ).

Links or suggestions would be great!

Thanks

Comment: ...how are your users going to see their images if you don't send them to them? Using traffic is inevitable, and App Engine's rates are competitive.

Comment: This is the reason of the POST :) I would like to see some discussion and opinions to help me and everyone in my situation to decide for the best option. Although Adam Crossland solution seems clean to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone is going to charge you to deliver your content, be it Google through AppEngine or Amazon through S3 or CloudFront or something else. You'll want to put together a spreadsheet into which you can plug numbers to see how the various alternatives work at different volumes.

[Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) is a good choice for delivering static content on the cheap.

In terms of designing your application, the only thing that you really have to worry about is making sure that you have to do very little work when the time comes to change your delivery source.

Personally, I think that I would create a [custom Django tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that generated the `<img>` tags for me; something like this:

`{% staticimg sunset %}`

that would generate html that looked like this:

`<img src='http://instagram.appspot.com/image/serve/sunset.jpg'>`

when I need to switch to my new provider, say *cheapo-cdn.com*, I change the custom tag code and redeploy my app with no other changes. Suddenly, smoothly, the generated HTML looks like this:

`<img src='http://cheapo-cdn.com/image/serve/sunset.jpg'>`

Answer (score 2):

Try [Google Picasa with its API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html). A while ago I had been looking for an answer to a similar question and it was a good solution.